# Does Ubuntu 14.04 have something like Window's DXDiag?

Tags: graphics

I need to find out how much video/graphics memory is in my Acer Aspire 3680-2419 laptop so I can try to install a game using Play On Linux. I know it has a Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 950 that's most likely integrated onto the motherboard but I'm not sure. But since I'm fairly new to Ubuntu and Linux in general I'm not sure how to find that info.

Answer (score 1):

There are various tools that can do this, including:

1. `inxi`

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install inxi
   $ inxi -G
   Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA G86 [GeForce 8400 GS] 
      X.Org: 1.14.3 drivers: nouveau (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1920x1080@60.0hz 
      GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on NV86 GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 9.2.2
   ```
2. `lshw`

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install lshw
   $ sudo lshw -C display
     *-display               
          description: VGA compatible controller
          product: G86 [GeForce 8400 GS]
          vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
          physical id: 0
          bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
          version: a1
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
          configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
          resources: irq:16 memory:fd000000-fdffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:fa000000-fbffffff ioport:dc00(size=128) memory:feae0000-feafffff
   ```
3. `lshw-gtk`

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install lshw-gtk
   $ sudo lshw-gtk
   ```

   Then:

   [image]
4. `hardinfo`

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install hardinfo
   $ hardinfo
   ```

   Then:

   [image]

While only `hardinfo` actually reports the memory available to the graphics card, it is trivial to get that from Google. For example, searching for `GeForce 8400 GS` finds an [NVidia page](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-8400-gs/specifications) which tells me that my card has 256MB of memory.

Comment: It is not *trivial*. For example, my [gfx card](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gtx-670mx/specifications) doesn't have a standard memory listed (I know it's 3GB because the OEM listed 3GB and `nvidia-smi` confirms it). By the way, I don't think those memory values listed are correct, because `lspci -vv` lists similar values with the same labels (`prefetchable`, etc.) for my gfx card, so I think those refer to something else.

Comment: @muru I don't know, to tell you the truth. `lspci -vv` shows me 256M which is the same as shown in `hardinfo` and the Nvidia page.

Comment: Coincidence? Because I checked the output again, and I see it's the exact same values (16, non-prefetchable, 256 and 32, prefetchable). And for my integrated Intel GPU (on a Haswell i5) are 4M, non-prefetchable and 256 prefetchable. Is 256 some magic number? O.o

Comment: @muru well, it's 2^8 :) But yes, I don't really know what those numbers are. I think the best bet is to find out the card's model and then search the interwebs.